# Add text under image

Tags: image, text, addition

I'm looking for a way to place text under my images and want to keep it there when changing browser size (if possible make text bigger and smaller when doing so, but not necessary). When I use a div around an image the other images seem to disappear. 
This is the link to the site:
http://www.noortjepalmers.be/portraits.html

Thanx.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a div around each image, give it a class like "image-container" and then in your css you set

```
.image-container {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Thanx, I got the text next to the pictures but it stays on the left or the right not underneath the image.